# Having difficulty with this calculus problem incorporating many different things

Tags: calculus

i am having trouble with this problem and couldn't find it anywhere else so decided to post this question

Q: P(x) is a 4th degree polynomial such that

1) $P(-x) = P(x)$

2) $P(x) \ge  0 $

3) $P(0) = 1 $

4) $P(x)$ has exactly two local minimum at $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $|x_1-x_2| = 2$

$y=1$ line touches the curve at certain point and enclosed area between the line and the curve is $(\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{15})$

Let $g(x)$ be a 2nd degree polynomial 
$g(x) = Ax^2+Bx+C$ ($A \neq 0$) such that  $$\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{P(x)-g(x)-g(-x)}{x^2})$$ is finite and equal to slope of tangent of $g(x)$ at $x= -1$. Also $P(x)$ and 
$g(x)$ have common tangent parallel to x-axis . Find $|2A + 3B + 4C|$

This was as far as i got :

Ans :

let P(x) = a$x^4$+b$x^2$+1 (since P(0) =1)

P'(x) = 4a$x^3$+2bx =0

so x=0 or $x^2$ = +- $\sqrt{\frac{-b}{2a}}$ [either b or a is -ve for sqrt to be defined]

i assumed b to be -ve so x=0 becomes a maxima and other two roots are minima  and thus b=2a [ using x1-x2 =2 ]

so my P(x) = a$x^4$ -2a$x^2$ + 1

Now i double differentiated the limit using LH rule to get $$\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{6x^2 -2-4A}{2})$$

slope of g(x) at x=-1 would be B-2A

so using the limit i got -2 -4A = 2B-4A

B=-1 Thats as far as i got

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math.se. You are much more likely to get a positive response, and help, if you show that you've put in some effort to solve the problem yourself. Knowing where you're stuck or confused will let people give you more useful help.

Comment: Thanks for the response , i tried to solve the problem :  first i made a general expression of P(x) and since its even i figured it has only even powers. Then i used differentiation to find x1 and x2 and  got a relation b/w the coefficients of $x^2$ and $x^4$. Further i was able to find the finite constant value of limit to find a relation b/w A and B but on the whole i wasn't able to put together enough information to find A , B and C.

Comment: Great start! You should include that in your post, with your working.

Comment: Alright thanks , i edited the question to include my working.